# How can I overwrite/control the default lookup on a form's super() call for a lookup?

Tags: axapta, x++

Specifically \Forms\SalesCreateOrder\Data Sources\SalesTable\Fields\CustAccount\lookup

**Where does the super() call go to?  What determines the fields that are populated with this?**

The EDT is CustAccount, and I don't see a "FormHelp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `super()` calls the `performDBLookup` method of the control, which creates the lookup form .

You can read all about it on [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Lookups#Automatic_lookups).

> Axapta uses a simple system to determine which fields to display in an automatically created lookup.
>   If no special changes are made, then the fields shown on the lookup are determined by the following information from the base table:
>
> - The field(s) responsible for the relation
> - TitleField1
> - TitleField2
> - The first field of every index of the table (in the order of the index-id)